# How can I check that PHP script execute by Cron Tab wget?

Tags: php, cron, wget

How can I check in my PHP script, that script execute **exactly** from *Cron Tab* by `wget` util, not from *web browser* by any user?

Comment: I *really* don't **know** what *you* are talking **about**...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, OK, maybe anybody else know

Comment: Does it have to be wget or can you use curl? That way you can set headers

Comment: @beingalex It must to be `wget`, because I want to execute script with CronTab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reliable solution. Anything wget can do, your browser can do too.

Your best shot is something like sending to wget to `http://example.com/mysript.php?accesskey=some+really+obscure+password+that+only+you+should+know` and check for that access key in your script. Of course, if anyone gets the password, this kind of protection is useless, but it's a far more consistent point of failure than blindly relying on User-Agent sniffing.

Comment: Plus, it's really easy to change the password :) Changing User-Agent sniffing logic is harder to do...

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to use `$argv`. Check if `$argv[1]` is a certain value and call the script from crontab with the value as argument, like so: `script.php argument1`.

Comment: In that case, use GET parameters. You can pass those with wget.

Comment: I think I need to use something like `script.php?argument1` ?

Comment: @magnetronnie True, but so can a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some arguments in crontab for your script http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.argv.php

Then checking for these args you'll know if your script is used from command line or web.

EDIT :

Seeing answers, let's make this clear.

Calls with Wget or cURL or whatever HTTP GET request WON'T PASS ARGS!
ARGS will only pass with local call (like : php script.php arg1 arg2).

Please, noobs, stop talking when you don't know about it, and try it out yourself on your server if you aren't sure about it.

Comment: wget won't pass args like that.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is a bit difficult to understand bus I guess you wan't to make sure a PHP script is requested by wget (that get initiated by cron)

Although it might be more efficient to call the PHP script directly by cron in this case you could check the server's logging end search for the user agent matching something like wget.

Comment: It should be noted that it takes maybe thirty seconds at most for me to change my browser's UA string to pretend to be wget.

Answer (score 0):

An insecure solution would be to check the headers for the User-Agent:

```
wget -d http://www.google.com/

---request begin---
GET / HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: www.google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
```

So you could do:

```
<?php

$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (strstr($userAgent, 'Wget')) {

   // wget Request

}
```

Comment: Does every server leaves this sign?

Comment: No, it could possibly be changed in the wget config. It depends on what kind of access to the machine you have that will be calling the `wget`. If you're looking for a super secure way then I suggest another solution.

Comment: I think if `Wget` word is **always** present, I can parse it with RegEx

Comment: I can change my browser's UA string to anything I want in under a minute, including pretending to be wget very easily. This is not a reliable solution.

Comment: this is terrible solution.

Comment: It's a solution to the question. The OP didn't originally request anything else.

Comment: There is a way better solution which works everytime, hence this one is just bad.